# Rails nested models and data separation by scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model, scope, nested

I have Teacher, Student, and Parent models that all belong to User. This is so that a Teacher can create Students and Parents that can or cannot log into the app depending on the teacher's preference. Student and Parent both accept nested attributes for User so a Student and User object can be created in the same form. All four models also belong to Studio so I can do data separation by scope. The current studio is set in application_controller.rb by looking up the current subdomain.

In my students controller (all of my controllers, actually) I'm using @studio.students.new instead of Student.new, etc, to scope the new student to the correct studio, and therefore the correct subdomain. However, the nested User does not pick up the studio from its parent - it gets set to nil.

I was thinking that I could do something like `params[:student][:user_attributes][:studio_id] = @student.studio.id` in the controller, but that would require doing `attr_accessible :studio_id` in User, which would be bad.

How can I make sure that the nested User picks up the same scope that the Student model gets when it's created?

### student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :studio
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :user_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

### students_controller.rb

```
def create
  @student = @studio.students.new
  @student.attributes = params[:student]
  if @student.save
    redirect_to @student, :notice => "Successfully created student."
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :studio

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :studio
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :studio_attributes

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Students, parents, & teachers do not *belong to* a user, they *inherit from* a user. As such you're looking for either single- or multi-table inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid that won't work. Teachers will be using this site to track students and parents. If the teacher allows, the students and parents can also log in. I made Student and Parent belong to User to facilitate this (If @student.user.nil? the student can't log in). If I were to use inheritance, I would _always_ have to have a User object for each student or parent, which would mean I'd have to play with random passwords, etc, to make sure they could not log in if that's what the teacher required.

Comment: Or you could implement permissions and have "log in" be a permission.